# Multipart POST works with Python requests but not treq inside Crawler

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests, multipart, treq

I have a crawler that takes pdf files and I want to integrate with a service that generate the OCR text from those PDF files.

I can make it work with requests but not with treq. All examples are from scrapy shell.

This works, returning the correct OCR json:

```
response = requests.post(endpoint,files=[('file', (fname, open(fpath,'rb'), 'application/pdf'))], data={'extract_method': 'raw'})
```

Testing, this simpler code works with treq:

```
In [28]: response = treq.get(endpoint)
In [29]: response.result
Out[29]: <treq.response._Response 200 'text/html; charset=utf-8' 30 bytes>
In [30]: response.result.text()
Out[30]: <Deferred at 0x164a14d7b38 current result: '<h1>PDF-OCR-Service Online<h1>'>
```

While this don't work, returning None:

```
In [25]: response = treq.post(endpoint,files=[('file', (fname, open(fpath,'rb'), b'application/pdf'))], data={'extract_method': 'raw'})
In [26]: response.result
Out[26]: <treq.response._Response 200 'application/json' 5 bytes>
In [27]: response.result.json()
Out[27]: <Deferred at 0x164a1443048 current result: None>
```

It looks like the file sent with treq is empty.